# How to include Plot into a custom function in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a custom function in r to create a plot but it is not considering the plot function to be included in my custom function. It is saying that my } is unexpected.

```
myqqplot <- Function (n){
  for(i in 1:n)
  {p[i] <- ((i-0.5)/n)}
  {qZ[i] <- qnorm(p[i], mean = 0, sd = 1)}
plot (p,qZ)}
```

When I do it manually it comes out fine.

```
  for(i in 1:30)
  {p[i] <- ((i-0.5)/30)}
  {qZ[i] <- qnorm(p[i], mean = 0, sd = 1)}

plot (p,qZ)
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: In R the "function" keyword must be lowercase, not "Function". All keywords are case-sensitive. Also you seem to have too many braces `{}`. If you want both statements to run in the for loop, make sure there is one set of `{}` that wraps all the statements you want to run.

Comment: there are several other problems with your first code block, have you ran through any tutorials on writing functions? https://r-coder.com/function-r/

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started, but as the comments note, you need to run through some basic tutorials. Since R is vectorized, you do not need any loops:

```
myqplot <- function(n) {
     p <- ((1:n) - .05)/n
     qZ <- qnorm(p)
     plot(p,  qZ,  type="l")
}
myqplot(30)
```